# How to delete item form list without using a delete dialog mvc C#

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am working on an MVC C# application and I have something similar to a "cart". 
Following in the steps of Amazon, I want the user to have the ability to delete an item but with NO pop up dialog.

This is my view button

```
            <button class="btn btn-danger feather icon-trash-2" onclick="delItem('@item.transactionId')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></button>
```

and below is my function in script

```
function delItem(transID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Services")',
        data: transID,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',

    });
}
```

The idea is that is goes to the postMethod and performs the delete. However I am getting a "500 internal server error"

```
vendor-all.min.js:3 POST http://localhost:58004/Services/Delete 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Grateful for any assistance.

Regards

Controller Delete Code

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Transaction transaction = db.Transactions.Find(id);
    if (transaction == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(transaction);
}

// POST: Transactions/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
{
    Transaction transaction = db.Transactions.Find(id);
    db.Transactions.Remove(transaction);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to determine what the issue is server-side. Investigate the logs and if  there's no answer there, step through it in debug mode.

Comment: And depending on your backend configuration you may need to be sending in a DELETE, not POST. Need info on what your backend logic looks like.

Comment: I have added the controller delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. That could just solve it although I can't remember offhand if indeed it is a 500 error that is returned with HttpAntiForgeryException. Regardless, you need to include the anti-forgery token with your request (which you aren't) or (for debugging only at this point) temporarily remove the ValidateAntiForgeryToken.
2. Then you'll be able to step through the process if there's indeed another exception occurring.

I just noticed your `Delete` action too, and you don't include routing info for it, so it could also very well be causing issues. Again, not enough info.

Comment: Following number one resulted in a 404 error, Delete not found, and using POSt gives a 500 error. I am unable to step thru cause it doesnt see it.
I believe it's routing. How should I configure it

Comment: I'm assuming you got it solved because you marked it as the correct answer (glad you got at least to the 404 since that was the underlying issue). Make sure you re-enable ValidateAntiForgeryToken (and pass in the actual token in your POST) once everything is working correctly without it.